# Is there any way to search for questions that have a certain image in them?

Tags: support, images

Is there any way to search for questions that have a certain image in them? I am looking for a question that I got an image from, but can’t find it in search.

Comment: Can we make a feature request?

Answer (score 2):

No. The stack exchange search is for text so you would need metadata embedded in to the image in the form of a where to URL showing the image link. That text would be easily searched for.

I would recommend tin eye reverse image search or another search image meant to classify an image. Hopefully they have crawled and indexed either this site or https://imgur.com/

Comment: I wonder how difficult this would be to code a reverse image search. I mean Google did it, but then again Googles a multi-**hundred**-billion dollar company.